Storage replication change from LRS to ZRS
I was considering changing the replication from LRS to ZRS and i've found the description, which says no downtime is needed: "During a conversion, you can access data in your storage account with no loss of durability or availability" , does it mean that writing is also possible during the conversion?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/redundancy-migration?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&tabs=portal#downtime-requirements

Yes, when migrating from LRS (Locally Redundant Storage) to ZRS (Zone-Redundant Storage), the description you’ve found does suggest that there is no downtime during the conversion, meaning that you can continue accessing and writing to your storage account during the migration process.

However, it’s always a good idea to test the migration process in a staging environment to ensure that it works smoothly for your specific use case.


Does it mean that writing is also possible during the conversion?

According to this MS-Document
Yes, the document actually  mentions that no downtime is required in  specific  redundancy options migration. That  implies that the storage account should  be accessible for both reading and writing during the process.

"During a conversion, you can access data in your storage account withno loss of durability or availability."


The above line states that both read and write operations are supported throughout the conversion process.
However, for a high-write workload or a critical application, it would be sensible to monitor the migration process closely, or better, to execute migration during time of reduced usage.
You can use either Portal, Azure CLI or PowerShell to migrate from LRS to ZRS using the above document itself.
Reference:
Migrate Azure Storage accounts to availability zone support | Microsoft Learn
